# uninstalling WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, uninstallation, karbonn

I want to uninstall WhatsApp from my phone fully so there should not be any data left, as it was preinstalled its not removing fully. I have only 2 options, force stop or disable but they're not helping. I want to remove it with cache memory as while installing WhatsApp its showing error.

Also its showing low internal memory space

My device is Karbonn S2 Titanium  (1.2 GHz Quad Core Processor and 1GB RAM).

Answer (score 3):

You can't remove pre-installed apps without root access. These system apps are stored on the system partition, which is generally mounted as read-only and prevents non-root users from modifying it.

However, the system partition is also usually separate from the user partition where you install apps. That is, the system apps by themselves don't take up any usable space. As long as you `clear data` (instead of just `clear cache`), you can disable the app and it won't take up any usable space.

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings > storage> cached data and clean it, also in misc select whatsapp this will erase all images l, audio remember to back up it in other folder first